# Save data in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am missing something in below code, not able to save in correct format, Can you please guide where I'm going wrong...

**Python Code**

```
str_next_thursday_expiry = 23JUL2020
f = open("data/expiry.json","r")
with open("data/expiry.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(str_next_thursday_expiry, f)
```

**Output in expiy.json**

```
"23JUL2020"
```

I want to store this in below format, not getting what needs to be corrected..

```
{"expirydate": "23JUL2020"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_next_thursday_expiry = "23JUL2020"
with open("data/expiry.json", "w") as f:
    data = {"expirydate":str_next_thursday_expiry}
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
content = {"expirydate": "23JUL2020"}
with open("data/expiry.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(str_next_thursday_expiry, f)
```

Comment: Thanks tried this but still saving as "23JUL2020" and not "expirydate": "23JUL2020"